# SwiftUI: How can I interpolate multiple localized string keys

Tags: ios, swift, string, swiftui

I'm trying to create a single `String` out of multiple `LocalizedStringKey()` objects.

I'm using `Enum`s with `String`s to give the user options and then interpolating them into a single `Text` View like this: `Text("\(LocalizedStringKey(enumOne.rawValue)) \(LocalizedStringKey(enumTwo.rawValue))?" as String)`

The `as String` is there to prevent this error: "Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'LocalizedStringKey' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'"

Any help would be awesome. I'm struggling to figure out a good solution.

**Edit due to confusion:**

the `Enum: String {}`s each have multiple cases. They are used for confirmation dialogues throughout the app.

I'm using `Localizable.strings` in order to future proof the app, in case it may get translated some day.

Based on what the user is trying to do, a `View` is called that takes parameters for both `Enum`s. This ultimately creates a confirmation dialogue out of `LocalizedStringkey`s from the `rawValues` of the `Enum` properties.

It does not have to be accomplished the way I'm showing here in this question. But I am trying to create a `Text()` View out of multiple `LocalizedStringKey`s.

Perhaps this would be best accomplished using an `HStack()` and two separate `Text()` Views. But that seems like a subpar solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps this would be best accomplished using an `HStack()` and two separate `Text()` Views. But that seems like a subpar solution to me.

You don't need an `HStack`. You can join multiple `Text`s together with the [`+`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/+(_:_:)) operator and they will become one single `Text` view.

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(enumOne.rawValue)) +
    Text(" ") +
    Text(LocalizedStringKey(enumTwo.rawValue)) +
    Text("?")
```

Unlike an `HStack` which will always keep the `Text`s laid out horizontally, the new `Text` created with `+` handles line-wrapping "naturally", as if all the components are in a single `Text`.

---

Note that if you want to also localise the *format* in which these two strings are displayed in, e.g. instead of `%@ %@?`, you want to display something like `Choose one: %@ or %@?` in another language.

```
// in your .strings file...
"%@ %@?" = "Choose one: %@ or %@?";
```

You can interpolate with `LocalizedStringResource`s:

```
Text("\(LocalizedStringResource(.init(enumOne.rawValue))) \(LocalizedStringResource(.init(enumOne.rawValue)))?")
```

At this point it might look better to just have a property in your enum that returns a `LocalizedStringResource`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

How can I apply formatting to a solution like this? Just add modifiers at the end?